# Disable Shop page on Woocommerce to protect categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to disable "shop" page in Woocommerce. Basically im creating a shop theme to sell prints and image downloads for a photographer.

Because i need to create private galleries i created a custom post type where i use the woocommerce category shortcode to show products and then i password protect the post type.

This is a workaround for password protecting the woocommerce categories (if someone knows a better one please explain).

The problem is that is someone goes to /shop they will all products, including the "protected ones". So i need to disable the shop page and i need to do it programmatically on my theme functions. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit - 
Apparently the page setting I suggested below no longer works. If WooCommerce doesn't have a plugin setting to change it, I personally would use a wordpress redirect plugin like [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). This way you can automatically redirect them from the undesired shop page to whatever page displays your products. It avoids a 404 issue and keeps everything in tact. It also avoids editing template files which adds complications to non-developers.

---

Old Answer:

Have you tried Woo settings?

Admin area, left main menu, Woocommerce > Settings 
Click the pages tab.

Under Pages setup is "Shop Base Page", on the dropdown, there's a small "x" to right right.  Click that to get rid of the page.

If there are links elsewhere that need to be fixed let me know and I'll find the hooks/filters to remedy it.

Comment: The Pages setup does not longer exist in the Woocommerce Settings page (tested on Woocommerce 2.4.10)

Comment: This does not work, and there should be a hook for this IMO, or atleast something that works.

Answer (score 28):

To disable the shop page, copy over the `archive-product.php` file from the `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` and put in `/wp-content/themes/{Your Theme}/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

Open up the file and overwrite everything in file with the following code below:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$wp_query->set_404();
status_header(404);

get_template_part('404');
```

Save the file, and now your Shop page is gone and replaced with a 404 Page!

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as updating WooCommerce shop page option alone doesn't block access to the shop page

Comment: I would agree that, given the circumstances, this is the way to do it (personally I use a straight `wp_redirect(site_url(), '301')` in `archive-product.php`); however, having to create a copy of the template and then implement some kind of header-handling is pretty ridiculous after you've deleted the page and removed the WC option. There absolutely should be **at least** a hook for this, rather than WC _assuming_ that it can ride roughshod over your site configuration regardless of your settings & pages.

Comment: @indextwo - Couldn't agree more!

Comment: In my opinion this is not a good solution, because there are cases in which WooCommerce inserts references to the Shop page (for example in the cart, when you remove all products), which would then lead to a 404 page.

Comment: Or use a redirect wordpress plugin. It avoids editing templates and gets them to the page that has the products you want them to see.

Comment: @Dev - All of those references to the shop page are easily changeable via hooks and templates.

Answer (score 23):

Add this to functions:

```
function woocommerce_disable_shop_page() {
    global $post;
    if (is_shop()):
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'woocommerce_disable_shop_page' );
```

Docs: [WooCommerce Conditional Functions Documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-is_product.html#17-24)

Comment: I combined this will the redirect in the above comments, works great

Comment: hi, you can also use `is_woocommerce()` to disable woocommerce page completely, because if you are using `is_shop()`, user can still access through products page or cart or products category, you can see the reference here : https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-is_product.html#17-24

Answer (score 5):

WooCommerce has a filter for the array that it uses to create the Product post type: `woocommerce_register_post_type_product`.

Rather changing the archive template to force it to redirect, you can completely remove the post type’s archive, but changing the `has_archive` attribute on the post type on creation.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_register_post_type_product', function($post_type) {
    $post_type['has_archive'] = false;
    return $post_type;
});
```

You should then remove the shop page in the CMS by going to **WooCommerce » Settings » Product » Display**, and clicking the “x” on the “Shop Page” option.

You might need to flush the permalink cache, which you can do just by clicking the “Update” button in **Settings » Permalinks**.

Answer (score 5):

template_redirect is the last hook before page render so in my use case I ask if the page being viewed is the "shop" page and if it is I redirect to (in my case) a pricing page.

```
function my__template_redirect(){
    if(is_shop()){
        wp_redirect(site_url() . '/pricing/', '302');
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my__template_redirect');
```

Comment: Elegant solution, just have to also remove the 'Return to shop' link when emptying cart.

Answer (score 1):

The last suggestion didn't work for me with WP 4.6.1 and WooCommerce 2.6.4. Hiding products in the Publish tab works for me.

http://paperhedge.com/hide-products-from-displaying-in-shop-page-woocommerce/

Answer (score 1):

To **disable the default shop** page and **leave the /shop/ slug free** for custom pages use this:

```
function remove_woocommerce_default_shop( $args, $post_type ) {
    if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        if ( $post_type == "product" ) {
            $args['has_archive'] = true;
        }
        return $args;
    }
}
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'remove_woocommerce_default_shop', 20, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook a couple (or maybe more) things:

```
/* hide category from shop pages */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG, YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG-2 ), // Don't display products in the knives category on the shop page
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Change, obviusly YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG, YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG-2 for your cat or cats to hide from shop pages.

Then, you need to hide them from menues too, right?:

```
/* hide category from menues */
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );
function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = array();

    // if category and on the shop page (change it with is_woocommerce() if want to hide from all woo pages)
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
          if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG, YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG-2 ) ) ) {
            $new_terms[] = $term;
          }

    }
        $terms = $new_terms;
    }
  return $terms;
}
```

But i don´t think this solve 100% the thing, since then, what about search results?

Answer (score -2):

**Try this**

1. Create new page named "Shop"
2. Go to "woocommerce" > "Settings" > "Product" > "Display tab"
3. Select shop page named "Shop" then click save changes
4. Back to "Pages" then delete "Shop" page (keep the page on trash,
   don't delete permanently)

**This method works fine for me**